# Reorder factors by increasing frequency

Tags: r, tidyverse

How do I reorder factor-valued columns by frequency - in increasing order?

While the forcats package provides an explicit way to reorder a factor based on its frequency ([fct_infreq()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forcats/versions/0.2.0/topics/fct_inorder)), it does so in decreasing frequency order. I need the reverse order of the factor frequency/counts.

E.g.

```
library(forcats)
set.seed(555)
df <- data.frame(x=factor(sample(as.character(1:10), 100, replace=TRUE)))
table(df$x)

1 10   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
9 10  12 14 10 10  5 12  8 10 

levels(fct_infreq(df$x))

[1] "3"  "2"  "7"  "10" "4"  "5"  "9"  "1"  "8"  "6"
```

Is there a simple way to flip the ordering so that the least frequent factor ("6") is first and the most frequent ("3") last?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done simply by using [fct_rev](http://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_rev.html) as follows:

```
levels(fct_rev(fct_infreq(df$x)))

[1] "6"  "8"  "1"  "9"  "5"  "4"  "10" "7"  "2"  "3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Or,  you can do it in base R by sorting and resetting the levels.

```
xLev = names(table(df$x))[order(table(df$x))]
df$x = factor(df$x, levels=xLev)
table(df$x)
 6  8  1 10  4  5  9  2  7  3 
 5  8  9 10 10 10 10 12 12 14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with(data.frame(table(df$x)), setNames(sort(Freq), Var1[order(Freq)]))
# 6  8  1 10  4  5  9  2  7  3 
# 5  8  9 10 10 10 10 12 12 14
```