# Change values in factor vector to become sorted size of the groups

Tags: r, sorting

How can I change the values of a vector of integers, to become a number corresponding to the sorted size of groups.

```
a <- factor(sample(1:4, 20, replace=T))

a
[1] 2 4 1 4 4 4 2 4 2 4 4 3 2 1 2 1 2 4 3 1
Levels: 1 2 3 4

table(a)
a
1 2 3 4 
4 6 2 8
```

Sort table according to size:

```
a
3 1 2 4 
2 4 6 8
```

So now all the 3s will be 1, 1s will be 2, 2s will be 3 and 4s will continue to be 4

Comment: r u looking for `x <- table(a); x[order(x)]`?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45846965/5325862

Comment: As per my understanding, OP wants frequency for 1 to be lowest, frequency for 2 to be second lowest and so on. @TYL there is also `prob` argument in `sample` which you can leverage here by assigning different probability for different numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @RonakShah. Sometimes its hard to describe what you want in words.
Anyway the sample function I used above is just to create a convenient example. My original output just creates a vector by itself, so there is no need to sample a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` after sorting the values in `table`

```
set.seed(123)
a <- factor(sample(1:4, 20, replace=T))
b <- match(a, names(sort(table(a))))

table(a)
#a
#1 2 3 4 
#3 7 8 2 

table(b)
#b
#1 2 3 4 
#2 3 7 8
```